# CSS property to distinguish if a person has entered an input-value manually or have selected it from the auto-complete suggestions?

Tags: css, background-color, input-field

is there a CSS property to distinguish if a person has entered an input-value manually or have selected it from the dropdown autocomplete suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `:-webkit-autofill` in the css to your element. Then whatever is inside will be activated when the element is autofilled.
If you want more info go to this website https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/

-Hope this helps